Identify and Locate Idler Pulley Assembly for Mercedes Benz MBE900
I am trying to identify and locate an idler spindle and pulley that will work on an Mercedes-Benz MBE900 engine, such as used in Freightliner/Thomas school buses and Freightliner and Sterling Trucks.  My application is 2007 Thomas C2.  The pulley is not commonly used where the vehicle is not equipped with and air conditioner.
The pulley is smooth on the outside and mounts with a 12mm bolt.  I can find pulleys that would work, but have not been able to locate spindle or bushing to mount the pulley.


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

I found a reference to Freightliner part number 01-28042-000.  The outside of the pulley is 75mm.  The pulley was not easy to find even with the part number.  I purchased an old stock part from eBay.  It is a perfect fit.
